# Pandoc - How to generate Github Markdown table of content TOC?

Tags: github, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to generate Table Of Content for a Markdown file that works well in a Github repository with a command:

```
pandoc -f gfm -s --template template.md --toc questions.md -o README.md
```

The `template.md` is:

```
# Wielka Lista Pytań rekrutacyjnych dla Java Developera

$if(toc)$
$toc$

$endif$

$body$
```

The `questions.md` is:

```
# Spring / Hibernate / JPA
1. Rodzaje fetchowania (fetch lazy, fetch eager)
2. W jaki sposób mozna tworzyć zapytania w JPA? (Chodziło o JPQL)
3. Co to jest problem N+1
    - [Jak rozwiązać problem N+1 w Springu?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC4NmoO66Zc)
4. Na czym polega lazy loading?
5. W jaki sposób można wstrzykiwać zależności w Springu?
6. Adnotacja @Profile
7. Scope’y beanów
8. Jakie znasz serwery aplikacji?

## Spring Security / Security
1. Jakie znasz rozdzaje autoryzacji w Springu?
2. Co to jest OAuth 2.0?
3. Było pytanie o Base64
4. Pytanie o autoryzacje tokenem
```

And the output `README.md` is:

```
# Wielka Lista Pytań rekrutacyjnych dla Java Developera

-   [Spring / Hibernate /
    JPA](#spring--hibernate--jpa){#toc-spring--hibernate--jpa}
    -   [Spring Security /
        Security](#spring-security--security){#toc-spring-security--security}


# Spring / Hibernate / JPA {#spring--hibernate--jpa}

1.  Rodzaje fetchowania (fetch lazy, fetch eager)
2.  W jaki sposób mozna tworzyć zapytania w JPA? (Chodziło o JPQL)
3.  Co to jest problem N+1
    -   [Jak rozwiązać problem N+1 w
        Springu?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC4NmoO66Zc)
4.  Na czym polega lazy loading?
5.  W jaki sposób można wstrzykiwać zależności w Springu?
6.  Adnotacja \@Profile
7.  Scope'y beanów
8.  Jakie znasz serwery aplikacji?

## Spring Security / Security {#spring-security--security}

1.  Jakie znasz rozdzaje autoryzacji w Springu?
2.  Co to jest OAuth 2.0?
3.  Było pytanie o Base64
4.  Pytanie o autoryzacje tokenem
```

As you can see in TOC I'm getting some extra parts which I don't want to have, like this: `{#toc-spring--hibernate--jpa}` and what's more the links are actually not working.

Oh, and the headers are having those extra parts as well: `{#spring--hibernate--jpa}`.

You can watch it live on my repository here: https://github.com/sztukakodu/wielka-lista-pytan

I use `Makefile` to build the output.

What should be changed to have output with TOC without those extra parts & headers without extra parts & with all links working properly?

Comment: Do you get better results with `--to=gfm`? That should at least fix the broken links.

Comment: No. I've used external tool markdown-toc to be honest. You can check the Makefile: https://github.com/sztukakodu/wielka-lista-pytan/blob/a2d717044de9f21967af31568075fa5abc08ba05/Makefile